# What happens when I don't rebase and merge to master?

Tags: git

I have been working off of master branch for the past 2 weeks. Several people are also using the same code base and they merged their code to master in these 2 weeks.

My PR is approved. But for some reasons I cannot do git pull or git fetch and then rebase. What if I directly just merge it to master? Will something break or git is smart enough to see that master branch is ahead of my commits and automatically reconcile the code and NOT undo other people's work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer: Git is smart.**

If using the CLI, when you will ask to merge (`git merge`), it will try to apply your changes on top of `master` by "reconciliating" as you say: either there are no conflicts and it will succeed or it will detect some conflicts and ask you to resolve them manually and create a "merge commit" (it may create one even if there are no conflict, it depends on your config).

**The changes made by other people will be kept**, that's the power of a Versioning Control System.

When using GitHub through a Pull Request (PR), GitHub will expose the "merge" button only if there are no conflicts and the merge is possible, otherwise it will says there are conflicts and the PR cannot be merged.

*EDIT: however this often not recommended to do it this way as the result of applying your changes on a `master` that changed in the meantime might create inconsistencies in the code as you wrote some changes without knowing what others did, hopefully tests are there to catch this.*